# Minitest and setup/teardown hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have the following code in ***test_helper***

```
require "minitest/spec"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "database_cleaner"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion

  include Minitest::Spec::DSL

  setup { DatabaseCleaner.start }
  teardown { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
end
```

And if I write such a test

```
class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'test' do
    #some code
  end
end
```

setup and teardown are executed

But if I write test like this

```
class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  describe 'some test'
    before do
       @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    end

    it 'first test' do
      # some code
    end

    it 'second test' do
      # some code
    end
  end
end
```

setup and teardown are not executed. Why? Can I fix it?

Comment: Just a hunch, but I wonder if minitest/spec is incompatible with the setup/teardown hooks ... if you replace those with before/after blocks in the `ActiveSupport::TestCase` definition does it work?

Comment: @maxpleaner it is not working, i get this error `'<class:TestCase>': undefined method 'before' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class (NoMethodError)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `test_helper.rb`:

```
class Minitest::Spec
  before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Or, if you're using `minitest-around` gem:

```
class Minitest::Spec
  around do |tests|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning(&tests)
  end
end
```

Important here is the use `Minitest::Spec` class instead of `ActiveSupport::TestCase`.

See [database cleaner docs](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#minitest-example) for more info.